# How to visualize our network in Matconvnet?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

Is there any function to visualize the network like this? 
[image: network]

I want to visualize both dagnn and simplenn architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, install Graph Visualization Software (Grphviz) by this [link](http://www.graphviz.org/download/). Then as [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/+dagnn/@DagNN/DagNN/#print-print-information-about-the-dagnn-object) describes, you should utilize `dot` format to take advantage of Grphviz. For instance if you wanna to plot the whole dag network follow as below :

```
net.print('format','dot')
```

If your network is adapted to the SimpleNN structure, initialize a DagNN object from a SimpleNN  network and then plot it.

Comment: @Ahmet Gökhan Poyraz  For windows distribution, the easiest way to install Graphvis is merely download [this](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/windows/graphviz-2.38.msi).